# The "Apply Now" button disappears in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

In Google Chrome, the "Apply Now" button disappears after one or two seconds on [this job offer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/129220/softwareentwickler-net-c-sharp-prescriptive-orconomy-gmbh) with my account.

> [image: No Apply Now button]

I looked into the HTML file, and the button gets the `clear` class appended. I don't know the reason why, but this looks like a bug.

I only see this in Google Chrome. In Firefox, the exact same page works fine and the button remains visible.

Further investigation confirms that this happens for other job pages, too.

Comment: I looked into other job offer pages, there the button disappears for me, too. Thus, it is probably not specific to the link, which I posted.

Comment: No repro. Perhaps an overzealous ad blocker or privacy addon?

Comment: @Dima what Stijn said; that div is rendered with the clear class and we have no code that hides the apply button subsequent to page load. The fact that it removes the element a couple of seconds after page load indicates that it is probably a browser plugin of some description. I'd suggest loading the page in an incognito window and seeing if you get the same behaviour.

Comment: @DeanWard: I tried it in the incognito window. The apply button did not disappear. Thus, probably some plug-in lets it disappear. Thank you, for your help.